# Math quiz Application using reinforcement learning

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

I want to develop a Math quiz program using reinforcement learning.
Assume that we have 1000 questions in hand and 25 questions to be asked in each quiz. Instead of asking questions at random, program has to learn from the way user answer and ask the next question.

Quiz programme should be a reinforcement learning agent. How to design the solution and which are the reinforcement learning techniques to be used?
Example :
BoT: what is 5+ 1:
User: 3 (Wrong Answer)
Bot: Asked easy question or if correct answer asked a difficult question.

Comment: Are you asking how to build a model that would raise and lower the difficulty based on user answers? Or a model that would reward a learner by answering correct, and punish them for answering wrong?

Comment: @GKE  I am asking about how to build a model that would raise and lower the difficulty based on user answers.(correct / incorrect )

Answer (score 0):

PPO is a very common technique for these type of RL applications in the edTech space. You can take a lot of inspiration from this [article](https://assets.amazon.science/09/52/ef9488314113a1c8488b277956f8/reinforcement-learning-for-the-adaptive-scheduling-of-educational-activities.pdf). They use the RLgraph package and the PPO algorithm.

You would first have to define your goal/reward function. In your case, I would define the reward function to have something to do with the percentage of previous questions that was answered correctly. If this percentage is 0% or 100%, the reward is low (it's too difficult/easy). If it's close to 50% you might choose the reward to be high.

That way, the algo will move towards questions that get 50% correctness (are medium difficulty). You can play with the range (last 2 q's or last 10 q's).

As state-space, you can also include questions answered correctly, maybe characteristics like age etc. to help initiate the algo when the user hasn't used it too much yet.

As action-space, you can have all the questions. You could also cluster(e.g. difficult/easy, or geometry/algebra) questions based on your intuition and make the clusters actions, to decrease the action space.